# deleting a node in linear single linked list given the start of the list

Tags: c, algorithm

I have the following code which deletes a given node from the linear single linked list.
I want to know if we can still improve this program and does it break anytime

```
   struct node
    {
      int num;
      struct node *next;
    } ;


   typedef struct node s;

    void delete(struct node *first)
     {
            int flag = 0;
            s *ptr, *lastNodePtr = NULL, *deleteNode;
            deleteNode = (s*) malloc(sizeof(s));
            printf("enter the node value to delete");
            scanf_s("%d",&deleteNode->num);
            deleteNode->next = NULL;

            for (ptr=first;ptr!=NULL;ptr=ptr->next) //at least one element exist
            {
              if(deleteNode->num == ptr->num)
              {
                flag=1;
                if(ptr==first) //need to delete at first place
                {
                  free(ptr);
                  first = null; //i dont think we need to do this as it points to ptr and ptr is already null.
                }
                else // need to delete some where middle.it can be last as well.
                {
                  lastNodePtr->next=ptr->next;
                  free(ptr);
                }

                printf("successfully deleted..");
                break;
              }

              lastNodePtr=ptr; // taking note of last node visited..
            }

            if (flag==0)
            {
              printf("\n Couldn't find the node");
              return;
            }
      }
```

Comment: "struct node *s" and then "s *last" is one pointer too much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if ptr is the first element in the list to delete, you set first to null, not to the next of ptr. (sideeffect: you are not able to free the the rest of the list)

your EDITH: delete should return the new Head, better make it a struct node **first parameter which changes the first element if the first is the deleted one

BTW: never cast the result of malloc.

BTW two. why use for-loop? everybody uses while-loop with linked lists

BTW three: normal variable names for linked lists are "head", "list", "next", "prev", "last" with the nice side-affect, they are all the same length, so making it neatly aligned.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node
{
  struct node *next;
  int num;
} ;

void delete(struct node **pp, int num) {
    struct node *del;

    for (   ;*pp; pp= &(*pp)->next) {
        if((*pp)->num == num) break;
        }

    if (!*pp) { printf("Couldn't find the node(%d)\n", num); return; }

    del = *pp;
    *pp = del->next;
    free(del);
  }
```

BTW: there is nothing wrong with `for()` loops; they allow you to put all the *loop logic* on one line.